# Should I disable 'Prefer 32-bit'?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, 32bit-64bit

When I check the build properties for my application in Release mode, then I found out that the 'Prefer 32-bit' is enabled by default:

[image: Visual Studio build properties]

I guess Microsoft thinks that 32-bit is best for most applications, but when I check my task manager, then I see most applications use 64-bit mode. I can see some uses for 32-bit mode (if the underlying architecture supports it):

- Smaller pointer sizes, so lower memory footprint.
- Allow using 32-bit unmanaged libraries (i.e. COM components).

The only advantage for 64-bit mode -that I can think if- is a larger address space, so you should only enable it for applications that require >3GB of memory.

I work on a several service components (micro-service architecture) that require about 100-200MB per service, so it seems fine to keep it as 32-bit. It just feels weird to prefer 32-bit, when everybody screamed for 64-bit versions of webbrowsers (that typically use less than 3GB of RAM). What's the best option?

Comment: VS itself is still 32-bit.

Comment: There were definitely teething issues with getting the tooling and runtime for x64 as stable as x86.  But that's in the past, I haven't heard about a jitter bug for over a year and it is getting exercised well enough these days because of .NETCore.  Only remaining concern is the support you will have to provide yourself.  Your program will act differently depending on whether it runs on a 32-bit or 64-bit OS and that may be issues you haven't dealt with before.  Try it.